# Mongo Script always connects to localhost

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am building a MongoDB database and have being doing so on localhost. I have been doing it using JS scripts. I was testing the DB on localhost by starting my script with `var conn = new Mongo('localhost:27017')` and everything was working fine. But when I tried to run the script for the mLab instance, by using:

```
var conn = new Mongo('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds115671.mlab.com:15671/finance_tracker')
```

(obviously replacing the username and password), the only output that I get is:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
```

I then tried just using the host and port, as suggested in the [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/), and then using `db.auth()`, like this:

```
conn = new Mongo('ds115671.mlab.com:15671');
db = conn.getDB("finance_tracker");
db.auth(username, password);
```

I get the same message as before stating that I am connected to the local mongo instance.

How can I write my script so that it executes on the online Mongo instance?

**EDIT:**
Here is an example of the script:

*script.js*

```
conn = new Mongo('ds115671.mlab.com:15671');
db = conn.getDB("finance_tracker");
db.auth('username', 'password');

db.users.insert({
    firstName: 'eddard',
    surname: 'stark',
    email: 'eddardstark@gmail.com',
    group: ObjectId()
});

var eddardstark = db.users.findOne({email:'eddardstark@gmail.com'});
var groupOneOid = eddardstark.group;

db.users.createIndex({email:1}, {unique: true});

db.users.insertMany([{
    userFirstName: 'catelyn',
    surname: 'tully',
    email: 'catelynstark@gmail.com',
    group: groupOneOid
}, {
    userFirstName: 'robb',
    surname: 'stark',
    email: 'robbstark@gmail.com',
    group: groupOneOid
}])
```

This is then run from the command line using `mongo script.js`

Comment: Hi @KajhiitKnight how are you executing/starting your script? Can you specify the command you were using?

Comment: I'm using `mongo path/to/script.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are seeing that output in the console because you are calling the script with

```
mongo script.js.
```

Which connects to localhost by default. You are not seeing that because of your connection statement inside the JS file.

If you  want to run a JS script in a mongo shell to mlab. Do something like this.

```
mongo ds115671.mlab.com:15671/finance_tracker -u <user> -p <password> script.js
```

This will connect to your mlab mongodb and then will run your script.
Then in you script.js you could have something like this statement.

```
db['users'].insert({'test': 'test'});
```

Example above will insert the document into users collection. Not sure what you want to run in your script, so I just wrote an example of my own. I hope this helps.

Comment: oh your update got posted while I was writing an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you first connecting to mLab MongoDB through the shell or are you executing the scripts from your computer? If you are shelling to mLab then you are already connected and your scripts can start querying without connecting. If you are running the scripts on your computer then working example is shown below:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds115671.mlab.com:15671/finance_tracker', function(err, db) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
  db.close();
});
```